# How to create a list of Classes in C#

Tags: c#, list, class

I am trying to improve a piece of code that I wrote but I need your help.

Basically, I have 2 classes `TypeARecommendationForm` and `TypeBRecommendationForm` that are inherited from `GenericRecommendationForm` and I am trying to copy the object `oRecommendation` in a new object.

For that I am checking the type to see which class to use.

The problem is that sometimes I create new classes that inherit from `GenericRecommendationForm` and I have to go through the all codes to see where to add these if statements as I have them at several places.

What I would like is to have like a list of the classes so that when I add a new classes I just need to add it to the list.

Does anyone know of a way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
GenericRecommendationForm oRecommendation= new GenericRecommendationForm ();
...
if (oRecommendation.GetType() == typeof(TypeARecommendationForm))
{
    recommendationForm = new TypeARecommendationForm((TypeARecommendationForm)oRecommendation);
}
if (oRecommendation.GetType() == typeof(TypeBRecommendationForm))
{
    recommendationForm = new TypeBRecommendationForm((TypeBRecommendationForm)oRecommendation);
}
else if (oRecommendation.GetType() == typeof(GenericRecommendationForm))
{
    recommendationForm = new GenericRecommendationForm(oRecommendation);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Create List of Type `List<object>`

Comment: The line `GenericRecommendationForm oRecommendation= new GenericRecommendationForm ();` will always result in the last `else if` to be executed. I assume that line is just for illustration purposes and doesn't exist in your real code?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inherit

Comment: You are right, I forgot the else of the second if. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: You can't have a list of classes you can only have list of objects or list of object types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to give your `GenericRecommendationForm` a virtual `Clone` method that all derived forms override.

```
public class GenericRecommendationForm 
{
    // ...

    public virtual GenericRecommendationForm Clone()
    {
        return new GenericRecommendationForm(this);
    }
}

public class TypeARecommendationForm
{
    // ...

    public override GenericRecommendationForm Clone()
    {
        return new TypeARecommendationForm(this);
    }
}

public class TypeBRecommendationForm
{
    // ...

    public override GenericRecommendationForm Clone()
    {
        return new TypeBRecommendationForm(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `List<Type>` to store your classes (well the types of your classes actually).

when you'll need to add another class, just use this:

```
List<Type> _classes = new List<Type>();
_classes.Add(typeof(YourClass));
```

Then when you test the type of your class:

```
foreach(Type t in _classes)
{
    if (oRecommendation.GetType() == t)
        recommendationForm = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] { oRecommendation });
}
```

But if I were you I would consider implementing it in another way.

Since you seem to actually clone the instance of your base class, just add a virtual (or abstract) `Clone` method to your base class, and then add the behavior you need in your derived classes.

That way you won't have to check for types at all, and can just do:

```
oRecommendation.Clone()
```

Comment: You were right, the virtual clone() worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome ;), since Daniel's answer is more complete about the `Clone` method you should mark his answer as accepted